# django-select2 not working with inlines in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-select-related, django-suit

Here are my models and admin classes:

```
---------------------Models-----------------------
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    buyer = models.ForeignKey(User)
    is_debit = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    delivery_address = models.ForeignKey('useraccounts.Address')
    organisation = models.ForeignKey('useraccounts.AdminOrganisations')
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    total_discount = models.IntegerField()
    tds = models.IntegerField()
    mode_of_payment = models.ForeignKey(ModeOfPayment)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Purchase Orders"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.id)

----------------------------------Admin----------------------------------------
"""
This class is used to add, edit or delete the details of item purchased
"""
class PurchasedItemInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = ItemSelectForm
    model = PurchasedItem
    fields = ['parent_category', 'sub_category', 'item', 'qty', ]
    extra = 10

class BuyerChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    search_fields = ['username__icontains', ]

class BuyerForm(ModelForm):
    user_verbose_name = 'Buyer'
    buyer = BuyerChoices(
        label='Buyer',
        widget=AutoHeavySelect2Widget(
            select2_options={
            'width': '220px',
            'placeholder': 'Lookup %s ...' % user_verbose_name
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = PurchaseOrder
        fields = '__all__'

"""
This class is used to add, edit or delete the details of items
purchased but buyer has not confirmed the items purchased, this class
inherits the fields of PurchaseOrder derscribing the delivery address of
buyer , is_debit , total discount , tds and mode of payment
"""
class PurchaseOrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = BuyerForm
   #list_display = ['id','buyer','delivery_address','date_time','is_active']
    inlines = [PurchasedItemInline]
  # model = PurchaseOrder
   #actions = [mark_active, mark_inactive]
   #list_filter = ['date_time']
   #search_fields = ['id']
    list_per_page = 20
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        request.session['old_post'] = request.POST
        request.session['purchase_order_id'] = obj.id
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/suspense/add_distance/')
```

I am trying to implement `django-select2`, but when I use inlines in
`PurchaseOrderAdmin` it doesn't show the field where I have implemented
`django-select2`:

[image: screenshot1]

But when I remove inlines, it works fine:

[image: screenshot2]

**Edit**

Here is the ItemSelectForm

```
class ItemSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Media:
        js = (
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
            'js/ajax.js', 
        )

    try:
        parent_category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.\
            filter(parent__parent__isnull=True).filter(parent__isnull=False))

        sub_category_id = Category.objects.values_list('id',flat=True)
        sub_category_name = Category.objects.values_list('name',flat=True)
        sub_category_choices = [('', '--------')] + [(id, name) for id, name in
        itertools.izip(sub_category_id, sub_category_name)]
        sub_category = forms.ChoiceField(sub_category_choices)
    except:
        pass

    item = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Product.objects.all())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['parent_category'].widget.attrs={'class': 'parent_category'}
        self.fields['sub_category'].widget.attrs={'class': 'sub_category'}
        self.fields['item'].widget.attrs={'class': 'item'}
```

Comment: could you add the code for ItemSelectForm?

Comment: I have added the code for ItemSelectForm, please see it.

Comment: Well it seems like some js (maybe the js/ajax.js) is ruining select2's mojo. Maybe you could post any logs from dev tools or the rendered html in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by adding the following line in the static/suit/js/suit.js

Add:

```
(function ($) {
    Suit.after_inline.register('init_select2', function(inline_prefix, row){
        $(row).find('select').select2(); 
    });
```